# Heyzap Ads on Phonegap. Don't fetch video with tag 'default'

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, ads, heyzap

I write code below:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {

    HeyzapAds.start("HeyzapKey").then(function() {
        // Native call successful.

        // Start fetching ads
        HeyzapAds.InterstitialAd.show().then(function() {


        }, function(error) {
            // Handle Error
        });

    return HeyzapAds.showMediationTestSuite();

    }, function(error) {

        // Handle Error
    });

}, false);
```

Then see next page:
[showMediationTestSuite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIKdt.png)

Then go to Heyzap and have problem:
[didFailToReceiveAd with tag 'default'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1cu3.png)


Problem in my code or in Heyzap account preferences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like heyzap isn't aware of your game `com.luckycatstudios.guessywords`. Use the heyzap dashboard to claim your game, and you should be able to see ads.

You can use this link to claim your game:
https://developers.heyzap.com/dashboard/games/add_game

If you still have trouble, send a message to support@heyzap.com ideally with a copy of your app we can use to debug.

Thanks!

Comment: I have one launch, but after I loose my progress : ) I've same error, but my app is claimed. Maybe u have skype/fb/or other messenger? I wrote in last week in support, but I've only auto answer.